# Error with HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call function `test` after pressing on `Link`, but I don't understand what happens. My code:

```
var something = "123456789";
swal({   text: "<a href='#' onclick='test('"+something+"', "1")'>Link</a>" });
```

Output:

```
<a href="#" onclick="test(" 123456789',="" "1")'="">Link</a>
```

What I want to get:

```
<a href='#' onclick='test("123456789", "1")'>Link</a>
```

As you can see strange `=""` appears. Also, this happens in PHP too. How to fix that?

Comment: Your `onclick` has single quotes, but then you also have single quotes inside your `test` method call, so it thinks you are closing out the original `onclick`, not opening a new nested string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes:

```
var something = "123456789";
alert("<a href='#' onclick='test(\"" + something + "\",\"1\")'>Link</a>");
```